# Where to add a loop in this C code?

Tags: c, while-loop

I have an assignment which deals with creating a program in C where a user has to insert 3 integers and based on the input, it provides the user a type of triangle(only if its valid) it would create with those values.

The code itself works, I've managed to insert a few loops for testing conditions and making it a bit more robust.

However I want to provide a user the option to try again for different results or simply close the program. I have a feeling I'd have to add another `while` loop however I'm not certain exactly where and how to make the program work that way.

The loop will ideally replace the output at the end or in a case where a user either gets an invalid triangle based on input. When those cases happens, I want it so it gives the user an option to retry or simply exit the program

See my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    /*** Declaring triangle variable sides ****/

  float sideA;
  float sideB;
  float sideC;
  char ch;

  printf("Lets explore triangles! Please insert a value for side 'A' of your triangle:");
  while(scanf("%f", &sideA) != 1)
  {
    printf("You inserted an incorrect value. Please insert a number for side 'A' of your triangle:");
    while ( (ch=getchar()) != '\n' );
  }

  printf(" Now insert a value for side 'B' of your triangle:");
  while(scanf("%f", &sideB) != 1 )
  {
    printf("You inserted an incorrect value. Please insert a number for side 'B' of your triangle:");
    while ( (ch=getchar()) != '\n' );
  }

  printf(" And finally, insert a value for side 'C' of your triangle:");
  while(scanf("%f", &sideC) != 1 )
  {
    printf("You inserted an incorrect value. Please insert a number for side 'C' of your triangle:");
    while ( (ch=getchar()) != '\n' );
  }

  /*** List of conditions based on user input to identify if the triangle is valid and if so, what type of triangle they get***/

  if(sideA <=0 || sideB<=0 || sideC <=0)
  {
      printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'INVALID'.\n\n");
      printf("REASON: You cannot have a triangle with any side having a value of 0.\n");
      printf("Please exit the program and restart it to try again.\n");
  }
  else
      if( (sideA+sideB<sideC) || (sideB+sideC<sideA) || (sideC+sideA<sideB) )
      {
          printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'INVALID'.\n\n");
          printf("REASON: The sum of every pair of sides must be greater than the third side of a triangle.!\n");
          printf("Please exit the program and restart it to try again.\n");
      }
      else
           if( (sideA==sideC && sideB==sideC) || (sideB==sideA && sideC==sideA) || (sideC==sideB && sideA==sideB) ) /*** Code to determine EQUILATERAL TRIANGLE***/
           {
              printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'VALID'.\n");
              printf(" Your input creates a valid EQUILATERAL triangle.\n");
           }
           else 
               if( (sideA == sideB ) || (sideB == sideC ) || (sideC == sideA ) )/*** Code to determine ISOSCELES TRIANGLE***/
               {
                   printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'VALID'.\n");
                   printf("Your input creates a valid ISOSCELES triangle.\n");
               }
               else
                   if( (sideA!= sideB) && (sideB != sideC) )/*** Code to determine SCALENE triangle ***/
                   {
                       printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'VALID'.\n");
                       printf("Your input creates a valid SCALENE triangle.\n");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       printf("You have inserted invalid range of values, as a result your triangle is invalid.\n");
                       printf("Please exit the program and restart it to try again.\n");
                       printf("Goodbye.\n");
                   }
return(0);
}
```

Comment: You would add a loop around the parts you want to repeat.

Comment: Ideally that would be the cases where the user inserts an invalid set of values causing the program to output a message to the user. It would be right after that message. What would I have to type to do that. Would it be similar to the ones i've done already?

Comment: Some general observations:
(1) The assignment asks you to accept three integers. Why is your program using `float` values?
(2) Always try to avoid repetition in your code. Write a function that inputs a side length from the user and returns this value, then call it 3 times. (e.g., `sideA=get_side('A'); sideB=get_side('B'); sideC=get_side('C');`
(3) Your code will be more readable if you keep your `else` statements aligned with the `if` statements that precede them.
(4) The logic you're using to test for an equilateral triangle can be simplified a lot. I'll let you figure this out for yourself.

Comment: I used float integers because for starters triangle can have length with a decimal value, and it's for robust testing purposes. (2) I was advised by the person who assigned this assignment to me to do it this way.(3) from what I can see the if else are aligned . I could be seeing things wrong though. (4) thanks I'm sure it can be simplified. I'm working on improving it once I get it as robust as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be easily achieved with a do while loop.

Try this algorithm

```
char a;
do
  {
    /*  Your code */
    printf(" Do you want to do more ( Y/N ) " );
    scanf( " %c",a );
  } while( a == 'Y' || a == 'y' );
```

Now, here's that code implemented in your code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    /*** Declaring triangle variable sides ****/

  float sideA;
  float sideB;
  float sideC;
  char a;

  do 
   {

      printf("Lets explore triangles! Please insert a value for side 'A' of your triangle:");
      while(scanf("%f", &sideA) != 1)
       {
         printf("You inserted an incorrect value. Please insert a number for side 'A' of your triangle:");
         while ( (getchar()) != '\n' );
       }

      printf(" Now insert a value for side 'B' of your triangle:");
      while(scanf("%f", &sideB) != 1 )
       {
         printf("You inserted an incorrect value. Please insert a number for side 'B' of your triangle:");
         while ( (getchar()) != '\n' );
       }

      printf(" And finally, insert a value for side 'C' of your triangle:");
      while(scanf("%f", &sideC) != 1 )
       {
         printf("You inserted an incorrect value. Please insert a number for side 'C' of your triangle:");
         while ( (getchar()) != '\n' );
       }

      /*** List of conditions based on user input to identify if the triangle is valid and if so, what type of triangle they get***/

      if(sideA <=0 || sideB<=0 || sideC <=0)
       {
           printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'INVALID'.\n\n");
           printf("REASON: You cannot have a triangle with any side having a value of 0.\n");
       }
      else if( (sideA+sideB<sideC) || (sideB+sideC<sideA) || (sideC+sideA<sideB) )
       {
         printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'INVALID'.\n\n");
         printf("REASON: The sum of every pair of sides must be greater than the third side of a triangle.!\n");
       }
      else if( (sideA==sideC && sideB==sideC) || (sideB==sideA && sideC==sideA) || (sideC==sideB && sideA==sideB) ) /*** Code to determine EQUILATERAL TRIANGLE***/
       {
         printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'VALID'.\n");
         printf(" Your input creates a valid EQUILATERAL triangle.\n");
       }
      else if( (sideA == sideB ) || (sideB == sideC ) || (sideC == sideA ) )/*** Code to determine ISOSCELES TRIANGLE***/
       {
         printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'VALID'.\n");
         printf("Your input creates a valid ISOSCELES triangle.\n");
       }
      else if( (sideA!= sideB) && (sideB != sideC) )/*** Code to determine SCALENE triangle ***/
       {
         printf("YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'VALID'.\n");
         printf("Your input creates a valid SCALENE triangle.\n");
       }
      else
       {
         printf("You have inserted invalid range of values, as a result your triangle is invalid.\n");
       }
      printf("Do you want to try again ( Y/N  )");
      scanf(" %c",&a);

   }while( a=='Y' || a=='y'  );

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Would this work even after a case where it says " "YOUR TRIANGLE IS 'INVALID'
 "REASON: The sum of every pair of sides must be greater than the third side of a triangle? Like after it says this, then it would ask the user the question to repeat? would it still apply to this? Or do I have to ad a `while` loop on each case I want it to repeat?

Comment: @Shivarn , Yes and No, you don't have to add another loop, just try it out

Comment: Thanks Arun, it worked perfectly like I wanted. However when I compile the program I get a warning `W8004  Line 79: 'ch' is assigned a value that is never used in function main... Is that something normal considering when we discussed the while loop last time, you used the ch to stop a user inserting anything other than a integer.

Comment: You can remove the `ch` . You don't need it for this code. `ch` is only required when you want to check for EOF, which I did not add to this code. I'll edit it.

Comment: That worked perfectly. @Arun A.S Thank you very much for your help. There is one last thing I want to ask from you. If you run the program, and when it asks you to insert something, you insert nothing and press enter, the program simply goes to a new line. How would we go around stopping that from happening and a message like previous statements would occur for such a case

Comment: @Shivarn , I don't really know how we can do that, maybe you will have to accept the values as a string and later convert it, or use some other function other than `scanf()` . But, I may be wrong. The thing is , I'm not sure about it. Sorry......

Comment: That's ok. you've been more than helpful. Appreciate your time. You're explanations are truly easy to understand and your methods are easy to follow. Thanks

Comment: @Shivarn , glad to be of help ...  :)

Answer (score 0):

Place all the code inside `main()` in a separate function like `HandleOneTriangle()`

Then inside main you put this loop (pseudo code):

```
main()
{
     while(true)
     {
         HandleOneTriangle();
         boll answer = AskUserIfHeWantsOneMore();
         if(!answer) break;
     }
     SayGoodbye();
}
```